# Awk to remove characters from start of string in specific column

Tags: awk, gsub

Text as follows:

```
1.6M    2014-08-21 20:56        ./file1
1.6M    2014-08-22 10:59        ./file2
24K     2014-08-26 10:39        ../file3
0       2014-08-21 14:12        ./file4
0       2014-08-22 18:05        ../file5
1.5M    2014-08-22 04:15        ./file6
8.0K    2014-08-20 20:31        ../file7
```

I want the output to be time ordered:

```
8.0K    2014-08-20 20:31        ../file7
0       2014-08-21 14:12        ./file4
1.6M    2014-08-21 20:56        ./file1
1.5M    2014-08-22 04:15        ./file6
1.6M    2014-08-22 10:59        ./file2
0       2014-08-22 18:05        ../file5
24K     2014-08-26 10:39        ../file3
```

Then I want the leading `./` to be removed but NOT `../` and only size and filename to be printed...

So far I've got:

```
sort -k 2 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="\t"} {gsub(/.\//, ""); print}'
```

Which gives:

```
8.0K        .file7
0           file4
1.6M        file1
1.5M        file6
1.6M        file2
0           .file5
24K         .file3
```

How can I make gsub only apply to start (first 2 characters) of coloumn 3 so that `../fileX` doesn't become `.fileX`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out... was very close :), just needed to slightly alter gsub command

**Edited**

```
{gsub(/^\.\//, "", $3)
```

Comment: You'll also want to escape the `.` => `/^\.\//`. Since `.` is the regex special character for "match any character", your expression will remove the first 2 chars from the string "a/b/c"

Answer (score 2):

Nice you figured a way out. Here's my solution with sed.

```
sort -k 2 tt | sed -r 's| \.{1}/| |'
```

Example:

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ sort -k 2 tt | sed -r 's| \.{1}/| |'
8.0K    2014-08-20 20:31        ../file7
0       2014-08-21 14:12        file4
1.6M    2014-08-21 20:56        file1
1.5M    2014-08-22 04:15        file6
1.6M    2014-08-22 10:59        file2
0       2014-08-22 18:05        ../file5
24K     2014-08-26 10:39        ../file3
```

Here the idea is to simply remove "./" which is preceded by a space. i.e remove " ./" or in other words, substitute " ./" with " " (space).substitution with space is only to maintain the indentation. -r in sed command is for regular expression support. sed 's|a|b|' means substitute first occurrence of "a" with "b". Thus in our case, substitution happens in 's| .{1}/| |. " .{1}/" means "single space followed by 1 '.' character". dot character needs to be escaped else sed interprets it as any character.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Can you explain the sed command though, I'm not quite sure I understand it? and the `tt` in sort?

Comment: @Patrick: 'tt' is the name of the file which contains your input text. If you are not at all familiar with sed, i would suggest you do some study on that. http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html is a good place to start. I'll edit my answer with explanation...